# Hadoop library support for Java 11

Tags: hadoop, java-11

Currently we have java application which runs on Java 8 with Hadoop-main 3.1.0. Now I want to upgrade it to Java 11. Since Hadoop-main 3.1.0 doesn’t support Java 11, I need to upgrade it to Hadoop main 3.3.x and still it’s supporting Java 11 runtime only. I’m not sure whether I need to compile my code in Java 8 and run it Java 11 in production or should I wait for Hadoop to support Java 11 fully?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The Hadoop documentation refers to the Hadoop classes themselves, rather than client-specific code.

However, if you try to run Java 11+ compiled JARs in YARN, where YARN does not have JRE 11+ installed on the NodeManagers, then you should expect class loading issues, yes.

Therefore, yes, compile to the lowest available JRE version, but this should not prevent you from installing JDK 11/17 on  your development / build machines, assuming you configure your build tools to target a lower version.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do you mean, we can compile in Java 11 if set the target/source as Java 8 in the build.gradle?

Comment: Should be possible, yes

Comment: Also, in the production server side, we should install Java 11 and Hadoop 3.3.x right?

Comment: That's correct. Are you having any particular error?